VueUse useStorage - Store array of objects with limit
I'm using useStorage (@vueuse/core). I'm trying to store searches performed by the user on the site. Each index in the array looks like this:
export type TSearchHistoryItem = {
  tab: string,
  inventory?: {
    id: number | null,
    name: string | null
  },
  keyword?: string | null,
  city: {
    id: number | null,
    name: string | null
  },
  radius: number | null,
  label?: string
}

I want to store up to 10 searches maximum in the localStorage. Thank you.

Your question is unclear regarding what you are going to do with it, but here is how you add a limit. Once the condition is met, it won't add to the local storage anymore. This can be adjusted depending on your needs.


<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core';

interface TSearchHistoryItem {
  tab: string,
  inventory?: {
    id: number | null,
    name: string | null
  },
  keyword?: string | null,
  city: {
    id: number | null,
    name: string | null
  },
  radius: number | null,
  label?: string
}

const searched: TSearchHistoryItem[] = []
const searchStrorage = useStorage('history_search', searched)
function handleSearch() {
  if (searchStrorage.value.length < 10) {
    const values: TSearchHistoryItem = {
      tab: 'Tab 1',
      inventory: {
        id: 1234,
        name: 'Name'
      },
      keyword: 'Keyword',
      city: {
        id: 1234,
        name: 'City'
      },
      radius: 12345,
      label: 'Hello Label'
    }
    useStorage('history_search', searchStrorage.value.push(values))
  } else {
    alert('Search limit is reached!')
  }
}

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="handleSearch">Search</button>
    <div>Number of Searched: {{ searchStrorage.length }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>



Tested and it works.
